# найти позицию первого элемента, не входящего в регулярное выражение

Tags: регулярные-выражения, postgresql

Нужно найти позицию первого элемента, не входящего в регулярное выражение.
Пытался использовать strpos, но ничего не выходит.
Например
select `strpos( '111/5191А','%[^а-яА-ЯёЁa-zA-Z0-9]%' )`
Хочу найти позицию символа **"/"**.
версия postgresql 13

Comment: Какая-нить хрень типа `SELECT strpos( '111/5191А', left( regexp_replace( '111/5191А', '[а-яА-ЯёЁa-zA-Z0-9]+', '' ), 1 ))`

Comment: Спасибо! Что-то я не додумался пойти этим путем)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как ответили в комментарии, это помогло.
Какая-нить хрень типа SELECT strpos( '111/5191А', left( regexp_replace( '111/5191А', '[а-яА-ЯёЁa-zA-Z0-9]+', '' ), 1 ))